# Weird looking vertices / vertex

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, subdivision-surface, bevel

Is this normal?

[image: Is this normal?]

and also this.
[image: and also this.]

I'm about to create sci-fi helmet thing. I've been watched some tutorial about subdivision surface and beveling and this happen when I add both of that modifier, so am I did it wrong or is this normally happen?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

[image]

Comment: That is the result of poor topology and the bevel modifier. You should strive for loops around holes and borders

Comment: Please edit your question and add an image that shows your object in edit mode.